# Handlebars Block Helper : each with sort

Tags: json, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I have an array of json objects which I output using a Handlebars template; I am currently doing using {{#each object}}...{{/each}}.  I now need to sort the objects by one of the object's properties, which again is no problem using a handlebars helper & coffeescript, however, I have a problem in my template in that I cannot work out how to iterate over the sorted array using each.

My research so far indicates that I probably need to write a custom Handlebars helper which will, in effect, be:

```
{{#each_with_sort array}}
```

My existing sort helper is like this

```
   Handlebars.registerHelper sort_me =>
     myArray.sort (a,b)->
       return if +a.sort_index >= +b.sort_index then 1 else -1
```

but, I am struggling to be able to use the sorted array in the template - for example, it is not as simple as

```
 {{#each sort_me(myArray)}}
```

The data is coming from a third party API, so I have to perform sorting in handlebars/coffeescript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to sort the data before it gets to Handlebars, then you can use `{{#each ...}}` as usual and no helpers are needed. This sort of approach is quite common with Handlebars, the template is often split into two pieces: a (Java|Coffee)Script piece for data mangling/rearrangement and the template proper.

As an aside, you'll want to adjust your comparator function to behave property. From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If `a` and `b` are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to a lower index than `b`, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`.

So you want to return `0` if `a.sort_index` and `b.sort_index` are the same, something more like this:

```
myArray.sort (a,b)->
  a = +a.sort_index
  b = +b.sort_index
  return  1 if a > b
  return  0 if a == b
  return -1 if a < b
```

If you must do the sorting inside the template then you'd need to add a custom `each_with_sort` helper to do both the sorting and the iteration, something like this:

```
# If you're always sorting by sort_index then you don't need the key argument
# and you might want to put the '+'-casting back in.
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_with_sort', (array, key, opts) ->
    data  = Handlebars.createFrame(opts.data) if(opts.data)
    array = array.sort (a, b) ->
        a = a[key]
        b = b[key]
        return  1 if a > b
        return  0 if a == b
        return -1 if a < b
    s = ''
    for e, i in array
        data.index = i if(data) # Support the usual @index.
        s += opts.fn(e, data: data)
    s
)
```

and your template would be like this:

```
{{#each_with_sort array "sort_index"}}
    ...
{{/each_with_sort}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zusq2tt4/

Comment: How would the code for a helper look like that iterates over the properties of an object in a sorted manner?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner JavaScript objects have no specified order so you'd need to convert the object to a `[[key,value],...]` array-of-arrays and sort that; or you could extract the keys into an array, sort the key array, and iterate over the sorted keys.

Comment: Thanks. I did the latter and integrated it into my own `#each` variant.

Comment: @muistooshort it worked great :) Thanks for that, the only issue that I have, is that I've lost my (at)index reference. It returns always 0 (Note: I'm iterating an object array). :S

Comment: @Guillermo: You're iterating over an object? An example would be helpful.

Comment: @muistooshort here you have the gist. https://gist.github.com/guillermosnipegb/12660ede0b344fe163de5f9409528faf

Comment: @Guillermo: Have a look at my updated answer. I think the `@index` stuff was added to Handlebars after I posted this answer, three years is a long time in software after all :)

Comment: @muistooshort you rock! Thanks a lot :) Best regards from BUE, Argentina.

Answer (score 1):

I just collect all kinds of javascript functions and push it to handlebars like so:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper({
    eq: (v1, v2) => v1 === v2,
    ne: (v1, v2) => v1 !== v2,
    lt: (v1, v2) => v1 < v2,
    gt: (v1, v2) => v1 > v2,
    lte: (v1, v2) => v1 <= v2,
    gte: (v1, v2) => v1 >= v2,    
    sort() {
        return arguments[0].sort();
    }
});
```

This way i use it as:

```
{{#each (sort students)}}
  <div> {{this}} </div>
{{/each}}

{{#if (eq arg1 arg2)}}
  <div> Delete </div>
{{/if}}
```

if you need many functions, you can split the helper for "if" functions and "each" functions ... just to make it more organized ..