# How to sort array by specific integer value in Handlebars NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sorting, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

As we know, Handlebars don't have sorting helpers installed in it.

I want to sort my "games" array by a value named "listing" which is an integer.

code :

```
{{#each games}}
     <div class='rblock3'>
       <div class='tit'>{{this.game_name}}</div>
       <div class='live_res'>{{this.game_value}}</div>
     </div>
{{/each}}
```

I'm getting my actual array by this code, but not sorted.

I've tried all the google option and handlebars helpers, but none is working.

Please, can anyone tell me how to do it, what code should i write?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please the following solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662031/handlebars-block-helper-each-with-sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars Block Helper : each with sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662031/handlebars-block-helper-each-with-sort)